New popup about cookies that just starting appearing about 12 hours ago
I just started receiving the following popup about 12 hours ago:

It happens on every page refresh and it happens on Home, Questions, etc.
When I click on "Necessary cookies only" the popup disappears completely and no longer interferes. Not until I click on a question or take any action at will require a refresh of the page. Then it shows back up, again.
I'm using FireFox (updated to latest, or at most, I'm one update back.) This popup does not appear on Stack Overflow. But does appear on Home Improvement and on Tex - Latex and likely other sites like that. Odd that it doesn't happen on Stack Overflow, but I've tried a number of times without getting the issue described above. That site just looks fine here.
I have also seen the words "Company Logo" appear on the left side of that popup, in the white area, instead of the two orange lines there.
I have not yet clicked on the "Confirm my choices". And I don't intend to, until I understand better what's going on. My expectation is that either clicking on "Necessary cookies only" should be sufficient or else that after I click that choice, there might be a "Save choices" option. But I would expect that if I click "Necessary cookies only" and if the popup goes away, which it does, then the choice is made and I should not see this again. But I do see it over and over.
I'd like to know what I may need to do in order to clear this popup, permanently. (I'd like to avoid having to save pending work and reboot the computer. But that may be what's necessary. I won't know until I try, I suppose.)
(By the way, I'm receiving it here on Meta, as well.)
EDIT: So, after experiencing this problem for about half a day it has suddenly disappeared. So, unless it shows up again later, I think this question has now become moot.

This is the kind of thing that needs to be posted on main meta so the SE devs can look at it, especially if you are experiencing it on multiple sites on the network.

@Null It was only a problem here for about half a day, then disappeared shortly after writing the above. I put the question here after first checking Stack Overflow and not seeing it there. In any case, I've got nothing to follow up on, anymore. Perhaps I should just delete it, now, since I cannot replicate it.

If it's just one user, it's likely that it has something to do with local settings rather than an issue that is affecting multiple users which would most likely be a site issue.

I have had cookie confirmation requests occur apparently semi-randomly. They seem to occur in clusters and then seem to stop for a while. I said "seem" twice  there as I had assumed it was typical glitches which occur and had not thought to look for any pattern or context. If it happens again I'll record context.

@RussellMcMahon Things seem to have cleaned up for me. Probabky cookies. Or could be something else. Anyway, I'm fine for now.

@RussellMcMahon Things seem to have cleaned up for me. Probabky cookies. Or could be something else. Anyway, I'm fine for now.
